# JMS Message Driven Beans

Tags: java, jms, message-driven-bean, openejb, apache-tomee

What is the practical (real world) usage of below Annotations for MDB (Message Driven Beans)
I am wondering if any real enterprise application would ever use these annotations as topic/queue names would vary by deployment and should be a configurable property rather than being a constant string.
Typical queue names would be jms///./.

```
@MessageDriven(
activationConfig = { 
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", 
        propertyValue = "javax.jms.Topic"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", 
        propertyValue = "topic/MyTopic"),
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "subscriptionDurability", 
        propertyValue = "NonDurable")
}
```

I am wondering if most practical usage of such annotations is only for convenience of testing.

Comment: Are you talking of the   **@ActivationConfigProperty** ?

Comment: Yes because properties like "destination" is like hardcoding